# Getting ancestor tags name using openxml

Tags: sql-server-2008, openxml

I am trying to get ancestor tags name using open xml in sql server 2008. Here is what i have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/Envelope/Body/*/TagParent/Tag')
WITH (
    [Name]    varchar(max) '../@mp:parentLocalName'
)
```

I need to get the name of the 3rd tag,*. I can successfully run parentlocalname and localname, but nothing works for parent's parent.
I have tried many varients of above, it just errors out saying namespace mp is not defined. Is it even possible to fetch that name.

Comment: @Bert Evans Yeah tried all those variations. @ mp simply stop working as soon as i put anything in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hacky, but should work, where `../../.` is the path to whichever parent you're looking for.

```
SELECT Name.value('local-name((*)[1])','nvarchar(100)') 
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/Envelope/Body/*/TagParent/Tag')
WITH (
    [Name]    xml '../../.'
)
```

[Working example.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75716)

Comment: I'll check this out in a bit, though i changed the requirements to not need this anymore,but this always bugged me! So any solution that works will be good enough for me :)

Comment: It gives an error saying select failed because following set option has incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'.

Comment: I'll try to find another machine to test this later.

Comment: You can turn quoted_identifier on/off yourself on whatever machine.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx